# Unity become not responding when running the following right-click-to-move code

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour {
public int speed = 5;
Rigidbody playerRB;
Vector3 distanceToPos;
Ray moveToRay;
LayerMask floorMask;
RaycastHit rc;
void Start () {
    floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Floor");
    playerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

void FixedUpdate () {
    moveToRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    bool moveKeyDown = Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1);
    Debug.DrawRay (moveToRay.origin, moveToRay.direction * 100f,Color.red);
    if (moveKeyDown && Physics.Raycast (moveToRay, out rc, 10000f, floorMask)) {
        distanceToPos = new Vector3 (rc.point.x, rc.point.y + 1f, rc.point.z) - transform.position;
        Vector3 unitDis = distanceToPos.normalized * speed;
        while(distanceToPos.sqrMagnitude > 0.1f)
            playerRB.MovePosition(transform.position + unitDis);
        }
    }
}
```

what's wrong with the only line in while?
unity won't become not responding when changing the while into if.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How can you change while into if ? They are completly different statements.
If you use if statement, it does

```
playerRB.MovePosition(transform.position + unitDis);
```

movement just one time and check it again on another fixedUpdate.
But if you use while, it will do

```
playerRB.MovePosition(transform.position + unitDis);
```

movement while 'distanceToPos.sqrMagnitude > 0.1f'

and if your MovePosition function doesn't make magnitude of your vector smaller than 0.1f, it will enter an infinite loop. So, Unity will not response.

Edit:
You must update distanceToPos in while, else it will always be bigger than 0,1f. Maybe you should try this,

```
while(distanceToPos.sqrMagnitude > 0.1f)
{
playerRB.MovePosition(transform.position + unitDis);
distanceToPos = new Vector3 (rc.point.x, rc.point.y + 1f, rc.point.z) - transform.position;
unitDis = distanceToPos.normalized * speed;

}
```

Comment: I mean if i use if, though it is not performing right, Unity will not have problem. I just wonder why the loop is an infinite loop, if that is the case. I tried by changing 0.1f into 5f but Unity still become not responding.

Comment: I didn't understand what you exactly try to do with this code, but if you expect to change distanceToPos.sqrMagnitude, try updating it in while. I edited my answer, look it.

Comment: Thank you! Though it is still not responding I know where I did wrong.